# GetStream.io - Delete a feed nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, getstream-io

I am using Getstream.io nodejs module.

I am creating feeds at run time and want to know if there is a way to delete a feed through code?.

I see in the code base that there is a delete interface but when I looked in to RESTFul API documentation, I did not find any end point to delete a feed.

But when I look at Ruby documentation, I see that there is way to delete a feed.

Please let me know how can I achieve deleting a feed in getstream.io from nodejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to delete a feed using nodejs. It is just a hack but it will work.

But remember that deleting a feed means, it deletes all the activities from the feed. The feed still exists and can be seen through databrowser. The follow/following relationship still exists.

```
DeleteFeed = function(params,callback){
  if (params.feedId) {
     var feed = client.feed(params.feedType, params.feedId);
     //remove followings
     feed.following({limit:25,offset:0},function(err,r){
        if (!err) {
           for (var i = 0; i < r.body.results.length; i++) {
             var tempFeed = r.body.results[i].target_id.split(':');
             feed.unfollow(tempFeed[0], tempFeed[1]);
           }
        }
     });
     // do something similar as followings for followers 
     //(I did not have to worry about it hence did not write any code)
     client.delete({
       url: "feed/" + params.feedType  + "/" + params.feedId + "/",
       signature: feed.signature
     }, function (e, r) {
        //DO NOTHING
        //console.log("Error -- " + e);
        //console.log("Result -- " + JSON.stringify(r,null,2));
     });
  }
};
```

Comment: If you want you could add this code to our JavaScript client and create a pull request for it, that way other users of the client library can also use this method. Btw it is not necessary to unfollow the feed you are about to remove since no new activities will be added to it.

Comment: Actually I tried deleting it and added an activity and I could see the feeds getting updated to the followings and followers. So, I thought it is safer to remove the relationships of followings and follwers

Comment: Yes sure in that case it would add the activity to those feeds. But why would you add an activity to a deleted feed? What is your usecase for deleting feeds?

Comment: The idea is to delete the entire feed not just the activities in the feed (including followers, activities, followings etc). Think of it as a cleanup. A typical use case is when a user is deleted, we want to delete all its feeds.

Answer (score 2):

The delete operation is currently not supported by the nodejs client library. There is an api endpoint that supports this operation: [feed](http://getstream.io/docs_rest/#feed), but the delete operation is not documented on the REST docs. You can delete feeds from the [databrowser](https://getstream.io/dashboard) on the getsream.io dashboard.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I was able to delete a feed using nodejs. I will provide my code as an answer.

Comment: The delete operation seems to have been removed from the rest docs and it now returns 404. @Matthisk can you update your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such thing by doing doing the *logical delete* behavior by:

- modeling the feeds design to have a logical delete
- use as must TO field as possible, so you can remove all activities of feeds added by To targeting field automatically
- consider a follow feed design. Instead of remove activities you can just unfollow the deleted feed
- map the foreign_id field properly in order of batching delete