# Deleting a feed using REST API

Tags: getstream-io

My requirement is to clear all activities on a notification feed.

Based on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020776/getstream-io-delete-a-feed-nodejs) I understand that there is an undocumented REST API to delete a feed and the dashboard truncate feed functionality uses it.
I tried to replicate the call with the same parameters as dashboard:

```
DELETE /api/v1.0/feed/notification/f8fa1d12-594a-4b2b-ac58-23c912d1335a/?api_key=...&location=unspecified
Host: api.getstream.io
Authorization: notificationf8fa1d12-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-23c912d1335a writetoken
stream-auth-type: simple
X-Stream-Client: stream-javascript-client-browser-unknown
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Tried to use the same but am getting this error message:

```
{
  "code": null,
  "detail": "url signature missing or invalid",
  "duration": "6ms",
  "exception": "AuthenticationFailed",
  "status_code": 403
}
```

Is this the right way to use this API? 
I am using this from Java code and believe that the Java client doesn't have this functionality built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to do this. You can do it manually from the explorer on the dashboard. Search for the feed, select an activity and press the truncate feed button. This is the easiest way to do this if manually doing this is sufficient.

It's also possible like you found to use the delete API endpoint to do it programmatically. This endpoint is not built in to most clients, including the Java client. The URL and HTTP verb that you used should indeed work.

From what I can tell from your headers and the response it seems like you are having an issue with supplying a correct signature. The easiest way to do this correctly is to use the built in methods in the library you're using to generate them. I'm not an expert in the Java library, but it seems like these methods are inside the `StreamRepoUtils` class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. he write token I was using turned out to be wrong. Your method allowed me to debug this and find that out.